# Telling PHP not to start a session if a session already exists

Tags: php, session

In my shopping cart for my eCommerce website assignment, I decided to use an if statement to check whether or not a session exists because I found that instead of adding IDs on the end of the array I was creating, it was only showing the previously clicked ID. I don't expect you to understand my unclear explanation, but it gives basis.

I figured this was because a new session was being created each time I loaded the page with an ID of an item I had clicked, so it was suggested to me to use an if statement to check if a session exists. Here's what I got so far:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)){
session_start();
}else{
//I want it to say not to start a session here
}
```

What should I put in the else section for it to not start a session?

Comment: dont use the else and you are done

Comment: yes, only if is enough.

Comment: There's no harm in calling `session_start()` if you already have a session. It will just resume that session.

Comment: Your problem is somewhere else if you're losing the previous session variable.

Comment: It seems that my IDs still aren't getting added to the array I have created. In this page called products.php, here's what should be passing over the ID: `echo '<a href="cart.php?id='.$row['id'].'" id="productBuyNow" class="buyNow">Buy Now - $'.$row['Price'].'.00</a>';` And on cart.php, here's what I'm trying to do: `if(!isset($_SESSION)){
  session_start();
  echo "Your session has been started.";
  $id = $_GET['id'];
  $_SESSION['cart'] = array();

  $_SESSION['cart'][] = $id;

  print_r ($_SESSION['cart']);
 }`

Comment: what does the print_r show, and why you are using [], after $_Session, means why you are giving session key, i thing $_SESSION['cart'] is enough, and more importantly are starting session on product.php or not

Comment: I'm trying to add the ID to the array variable I created called $_SESSION['cart']. Also, print_r is giving me what's currently in the array, which is the ID of the element I previously clicked. It's not adding all the IDs together, just showing the ID I last clicked. I just realized that the ID isn't staying in the array for the session, because when I leave the cart page and come back, the session appears to have started but there are no IDs in the array. I'm going to try using a cookie instead.

Comment: Post your code in the question. Comments have no formatting, it's really hard to see what you're doing.

Comment: i just read your last comment, the reason you only have last value in the session because you are overwriting your value, instead of overwriting it use push, so when ever you click the value get added into your session instead of overriding the $_SESSION['CART']; when you some thing like this $_session['cart'] what you are saying value should be equal to this, so it changing the value instead of pushing it, and that what you want

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you only initialize the cart session variable if it's not already set.

```
session_start(); // No need to test if the session is already started
if (!isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
    $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
}
$_SESSION['cart'][] = $id;
print_r($_SESSION['cart']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using push with an array argument instead of overwriting the value.

https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_push.asp